# IEWebBrowser 2" Failed / The object has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, vba

I have two notebooks with the same configuration (W10, x64, Office 16).

When we run the code to manipulate IE Elements / forms (instead of sending keys), one of the notebooks is running fine, while the other receives two errors:

> IEWebBrowser 2" Failed / The object has disconnected from its clients

The code:

```
Sub test()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "SOMEURL"

    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate my_url


    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readystate = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.document.getElementById("User").Value = "Login"
    ie.document.getElementById("Pass").Value = "Pass"

    ie.document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readystate = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: As for your specific error, I've found updating the reference to IE often works. Take a look at this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49164622/4839827 you can use that to find the instance of the browser again. E.g.`set ie = GetIEWindow("myWindowName",False)`

Comment: End With remains while I was editing to simplify and post.
Thanks to advice.

Comment: @Ryan Wildry - Things We try already: To refer ieframe.dll and shdocvw.dll from System32 and SysWOW64.. Nothing and also the suggestion to retrieve windows from GetIEWindow.

Important to say, in original Code the error raises when we raise IE.Busy and GetElements by ID. When we call window from navigate instruction it works well,

But like I said it is working in one Notebook, the problem is with the another

Comment: Try to add the site to the IE trusted zone: IE - Tools (Alt+X) - Internet options - Security tab - Trusted sites icon - Sites button - type the URL - Add. The error might be caused each time IE navigates to an untrusted site it restarts in a separate process, and all object refs are lost.

Comment: Also compare [compatibility](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=IE+compatibility+view+settings) and [mode](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=IE+browser+mode) settings for both notebooks.